# HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

**main**

```
ppService.deleteProductPart(cPartId, productId);
```

**@Service("productPartService")**

```
@Override
public void deleteProductPart(int cPartId, int productId) {
    productPartDao.deleteProductPart(cPartId, productId);
}
```

**@Repository("productPartDAO")**

```
@Override
    public void deleteProductPart(ProductPart productPart) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(productPart);
    }


@Override
    public void deleteProductPart(int cPartId, int productId) {
        ProductPart productPart  = (ProductPart) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria("ProductPart")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("part", cPartId))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("product", productId)).uniqueResult();
        deleteProductPart(productPart);
    }
```

How to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

If I modify method like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteProductPart(int cPartId, int productId) {          
    System.out.println(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
}
```

It returns:

```
SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] collectionQueuedOps=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])
```

But if I remove `@Transactional` it ends up with exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

I get it working by adding `@Transactional`, but now I am getting `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: ProductPart` although I chained `.uniqueResult()` to `Criteria`. How to fix it?

Comment: try beginning the transaction using `session.getTransaction().begin();` and see if that helps? Also the `createCriteria` method returns the `CriteriaImpl` so you cannot cast it directly to `ProductPart`

Comment: @Chaitanya, If I cannot cast like that then what is the easiest solution?

Comment: RCola, I am not clear on your comment, can you elaborate?

Comment: Also in your updated question you are just printing something to console so what you are trying to acive, it is not clear

Comment: Finally for the error `Unknown entity: ProductPart` , you have to change the createCriteria code as `createCriteria(ProductPart.class)`

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem! Can you please tell what is the difference between passing to `createCriteria` a string with class name and class (like that `ProductPart.class`)?

Comment: added details as answer, please check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Hibernate - Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203446/spring-hibernate-could-not-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for-current)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: ProductPart` indicates there is no entity with name `ProductPart`. One way to fix this issue is to pass the `Class` object to `createCriteria` method as:

```
createCriteria(ProductPart.class)
```

From API the difference in using String and Class is as follows:

[Session.createCriteria(String)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#createCriteria%28java.lang.String%29)

```
Create a new Criteria instance, for the given entity name.
```

[Session.createCriteria(Class)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#createCriteria%28java.lang.Class%29)

> Create a new Criteria instance, for the given entity class, or a
>   superclass of an entity class, with the given alias.

If you pass a String then hibernate looks for an entity whose name is declared as `ProductPart`.

Answer (score 6):

With Hibernate 4.x and Spring 4.x, just **Add @Transactional after @Repository** it will solve this synchronizaion exception.

Answer (score 1):

You must enable the transaction support (`<tx:annotation-driven>` or `@EnableTransactionManagement` ) and declare the transactionManager and it should work through the SessionFactory.

You must add `@Transactional` into your `@Repository`

With `@Transactional` in your `@Repository` Spring is able to apply transactional support into your repository.

Your Student class has no the `@javax.persistence.*` annotations how `@Entity`, I am assuming the Mapping Configuration for that class has been defined through XML.

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26203682/234110)

Comment: yees, i  added the annotation on my entity and it worked,
i commented the <tx:annotation..> because i was not going to do ecache and so i got the error