# Cannot persist Entity using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have table which holds `id` and 2 foreign keys. I need to add new record. Until `persist` method everything goes as expected - `productPart` is valid entity. After `persist` is executed - no new records appear in MySQL table.

**DAO**

```
@Repository
public class ProductPartDao{
    @Override
        @Transactional
        public void addProductPart (ProductPart productPart) {
        sessionFactory.openSession().persist(productPart); // doesn't work
    }
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class ProductPartService{
@Autowired
    ProductPartDao productPartDao;
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addProductPart(ProductPart productPart) {
        productPartDao.addProductPart(productPart);
    }
```

I cannot use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` because it throws error: `HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread`.

What's the reason? How to solve it?

**UPDATE**

in applicationContext:

```
...
 <tx:annotation-driven/>
...
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">

          </bean>
...
```

**UPDATE2**

Input is 2 `id` which used to retrieve `product` and `part` objects. Then this objects set as fields to `ProductPart` object and persisted. All retrieval methods for  `product` and `part` is marked as `@Transactional`. Why Spring and Hibernate are having trouble with it?

**UPDATE3:**

When code changed to `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` there is exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:988)
    at ee.t.mysql.model.ProductPartDAOImpl.addProductPart(ProductPartDAOImpl.java:19)
```

**The session object just before Exception:**
[image]

It can persist object when it's called from main with loaded `ConfigurableApplicationContext`. Spring web application with controllers fails.

**SOLVED**

Solved by replacing `sessionFactory.openStatelessSession().insert(...)`. I have no idea how and why it works. An explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have configuration transaction manager? And if yes, then post it for us. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: This link says you have fixed the HibernateException by using @Transactional annotation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933532/hibernateexception-could-not-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for-curren , so you still have issue with that post also?

Comment: Yes, because I was forced to switch to other method to access `session` I have unresolved problem. It has dirty quick fix just to make it work.