# Spring Hibernate - Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-orm

I created an application with spring + hibernate, but I always get this error. This is my first application with hibernate, I read some guides but I can not solve this problem. Where am I doing wrong?

This is the code of my application

```
ott 05, 2014 4:03:06 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
Informazioni: Refreshing   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1eab16b: startup date  [Sun Oct 05 16:03:06 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
ott 05, 2014 4:03:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
Informazioni: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [springConfig.xml]
ott 05, 2014 4:03:08 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
ott 05, 2014 4:03:08 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
ott 05, 2014 4:03:08 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
ott 05, 2014 4:03:08 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
ott 05, 2014 4:03:09 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
ott 05, 2014 4:03:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
ott 05, 2014 4:03:09 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
at coreservlets.StudentDAOImpl.create(StudentDAOImpl.java:19)
at coreservlets.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:14)
```

student.java

```
package coreservlets;

public class Student {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public Integer getId(){return id;}//getId

    public void setId(Integer id){this.id=id;}//setId

    public String getName(){return name;}//getName

    public void setName(String name){this.name=name;}//setName

    public Integer getAge(){return age;}//getAge

    public void setAge(Integer age){this.age=age;}//setAge

}//Student
```

studentDAO.java

```
package coreservlets;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public interface StudentDAO {

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory);

    public void create(String name,Integer age);

}//StudentDAO
```

StudentDAOImpl.java

```
package coreservlets;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory=sessionFactory;
    }//setSessionFactory

    public void create(String name,Integer age){
        Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Student student=new Student();
        student.setName(name);
        student.setAge(age);
        session.save(student);
    }//create

}//StudentDAOImpl
```

MainApp.java

```
package coreservlets;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springConfig.xml");

        StudentDAOImpl student=(StudentDAOImpl) context.getBean("studentDAOImpl");

        student.create("Alessandro", new Integer(33));


    }//main

}//MainApp
```

springConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="coreservlets"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_hibernate"/>
  <property name="username" value="root"/>
  <property name="password" value="password"/>
  <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
  <property name="maxTotal" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </value>
</property>

</bean>

</beans>
```

sql

```
create table student
(
id integer not null auto_increment,
name varchar(20) not null,
age integer not null,
primary key(id)
);
```

Comment: Did you try adding an @Transactional to your DAO create method?

Comment: You forgot to declare a HibernateTransactionManager, and to make the method using Hibernate transactional.

Comment: @itachi
is not correct, `sessionFactory.openSession()` the transaction will disable. Because they are not the same session. > Add the annotation @Transactional of spring in the class service @Patrikoko is correct! see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620355/for-web-mvc-spring-app-should-transactional-go-on-controller-or-service example: `@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {java.lang.Exception.class})`

Answer (score 249, accepted):

You must **enable** the transaction support (`<tx:annotation-driven>` or `@EnableTransactionManagement`) and **declare** the `transactionManager` and it should work through the `SessionFactory`.

You must add `@Transactional` into your `@Repository`

With `@Transactional` in your `@Repository` Spring is able to apply transactional support into your repository.

Your `Student` class has no the `@javax.persistence.*` annotations how `@Entity`, I am assuming the Mapping Configuration for that class has been defined through XML.

Comment: Please,Can you write the code of the application because it doesn't works..This is my first application with Hibernate

Comment: Annotation equivalent of <tx:annotation-driven> is @EnableTransactionManagement

Comment: Also, make sure you use org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional, not javax.persistance.Transactional

Comment: I have tried for hours to get the transaction to work and finally i used @EnableTransactionManagement instead of <tx:annotation-driven> and everything works perfectly. I cannot thank you enough Manuel

Comment: it is probably obvious, but still: @EnableTransactionManagement goes to your configuration class (that one annotated with @Configuration)

Comment: This worked perfectly after adding both `@EnableTransactionManagement` and `@Transactional` to my DAO class.

Answer (score 43):

I have had the same issue, but in a class that was not a part of the service layer. In my case, the transaction manager was simply obtained from the context by the `getBean()` method, and the class belonged to the view layer - my project utilizes `OpenSessionInView` technique.

The `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` method, has been causing the same exception as the author's. The solution for me was rather simple.

```
Session session;

try {
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

If the `getCurrentSession()` method fails, the `openSession()` should do the trick.

Comment: when upgrading from Hibernate3 to Hibernate5, I had to change the code from SessionFactoryUtils.getSession() to sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). Came across the same error at that time.

Comment: This gives the really nasty behaviour that if `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` succeeds then the session should not be closed but if `sessionFactory.openSession();` succeeds it must be closed

Comment: Agree @RichardTingle. Seems like openSession is a hack to bypass the exception. What should be the idle solution for this?

Comment: @Praveen what I actually did was have a service accept a lambda `Function<Session,T>` meaning "if I had a session I'd use it to do X". Then the method handles provisioning and (If neccissary) deprovisioning the session, and just returns the T. So external consumers of the service never actually get their hands on a session

Comment: This made my program run without sign of error. I am worried that I don’t have a transaction across multiple queries created this way, which means that I risk returning inconsistent results?

Comment: For me too many connections are opened and the application eventually dies. I used `netstat -nat | grep 3306` and I can see too many connections waiting for close.

Comment: This solution also leads to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33699600/14039503

Answer (score 14):

Add the annotation @Transactional of spring in the class service

Answer (score 5):

I had this error too because in the file where I used `@Transactional`  annotation, I was importing the wrong class

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
```

Instead of javax, use

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
```

Answer (score 3):

In your xyz.DAOImpl.java

Do the following steps:

> //Step-1: Set session factory

```
@Resource(name="sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf)
{
    this.sessionFactory = sf;
}
```

---

> //Step-2: Try to get the current session, and catch the HibernateException exception.
>
> ---
>
> //Step-3: If there are any HibernateException exception, then true to get openSession.

```
try 
{
    //Step-2: Implementation
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
} 
catch (HibernateException e) 
{
    //Step-3: Implementation
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

Comment: Hi! Isn't Hibernate supposed to do that by itself?

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow transaction to your DAO method.
Add,

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation=Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

over your dao methods.
And `@Transactional` should be from the package:

```
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
```

Answer (score 2):

I added these configuration in web.xml and it works well for me!

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
        <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Additionally, the most ranked answer give me clues to prevent application from panic at the first run.

Comment: I am using springMVC 4 and Hibernate 5

Answer (score 2):

My configuration was like this. I had a **QuartzJob** , a Service Bean , and Dao . as usual it was configured with LocalSessionFactoryBean (for hibernate) , and SchedulerFactoryBean for Quartz framework.  while writing the Quartz job , I by mistake annotated it with @**Service** , I should not have done that because I was using another strategy to wire the **QuartzBean** using **AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory** extending **SpringBeanJobFactory**.

So what actually was happening is that due to Quartz Autowire , TX was getting injected to the Job Bean and at the same time Tx Context was set by virtue of @**Service** annotation and hence the TX was falling out of sync !!

I hope it help to those for whom above solutions really didn't solved the issue.  I was using Spring 4.2.5 and Hibernate 4.0.1 ,

I see that in this thread there is a unnecessary suggestion to add @**Transactional** annotation to the DAO(@**Repository**) , that is a useless suggestion cause @**Repository** has all what it needs to have don't have to specially set that @**transactional** on DAOs , as the DAOs are called from the services which have already being injected by **@Trasancational** . I hope this might be helpful people who are using Quartz , Spring and Hibernate together.

Answer (score 1):

`@Transactional =javax.transaction.Transactional`. Put it just beside `@Repository`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was (using Spring) putting the method that fails inside another method that creates and commits the transaction.

To do that I first injected the following:

```
@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
```

And finally did this:

```
public void newMethod() {
    DefaultTransactionDefinition definition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus transaction = transactionManager.getTransaction(definition);

    oldMethod();

    transactionManager.commit(transaction);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and finally found out that the `<tx:annotaion-driven />` was not defined within the `[dispatcher]-servlet.xml` where component-scan element enabled `@service` annotated class.

Simply put `<tx:annotaion-driven />` with component-scan element together, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

My similar issue got fixed with below 2 approaches.

1) Through manually handling transactions:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
UserInfo user = (UserInfo) session.get(UserInfo.class, 1);
tx.commit();
```

2) Tell Spring to open and manage transactions for you in your `web.xml` filters and Ensure to use `@Repository` `@Transactional`:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>sessionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>session.factory</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `transaction-manager` to your `<annotation-driven/>` in **spring-servlet.xml:**

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="yourTransactionBeanID"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your dao class. It must be like this:

```
Session session = getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery(GET_ALL);
```

And annotations:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
```

Answer (score 0):

In this class above `@Repository` just placed one more annotation `@Transactional` it will work. If it works reply back(`Y`/`N`):

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly go through [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). In SO there is no custom of replying Y/N. If your answer works for the person they'll mark is as accepted. A helpful answer might be upvoted also.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comment of mannedear. I use springmvc and in my case I have to use as

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class UserDao {
...
}
```

and I also add spring-context to pom.xml and it works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it doing the following:

1. Add the this line to the `dispatcher-servlet` file:

   > ```xml
   > <tx:annotation-driven/>
   > ```

   Check above `<beans>` section in the same file. These two lines must be present:

   > ```xml
   > xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   > xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
   > ```
2. Also make sure you added `@Repository` and `@Transactional` where you are using `sessionFactory`.

   > ```
   > @Repository
   > @Transactional
   > public class ItemDaoImpl implements ItemDao {
   >     @Autowired
   >     private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
   > ```

Answer (score 0):

My Database table has mismatch column name with the Java Object (@Entity) which leads to throw the above exception.

By updating the table with appropriate column name resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a Controller trying to access directly to a DAO with @Repository.
Adding an @Service layer on top of the @Repository fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, which was resolved after adding both `@Transactional` and `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotations in the class where I used HibernateTransactionManager. Please refer to this link for further details:

https://www.baeldung.com/no-hibernate-session-bound-to-thread-exception