# Hibernate - the second query gives Unknown service requested

Tags: java, hibernate, session, hibernate-session

I'm trying to understand better how Hibernate works...

I've a problem I cannot resolve.

When the application starts, it makes a query

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
int result;
String query = "SELECT count(*) as posti_disponibili from occupazione t inner join ";
query += "(select id_posto_park, max(date_time) as MaxDate from occupazione group by id_posto_park) tm on ";
query += "t.id_posto_park = tm.id_posto_park and t.date_time = tm.Maxdate and t.isOccupied = 0";

BigInteger bi = (BigInteger) session.createSQLQuery(query).uniqueResult();
result = bi.intValue();
HibernateUtil.shutdown();
```

At the end I close the current session.

Then, after it, I have a second query to be accomplished:

I open a new session (the first one was closed with the method `HibernateUtil.shutdown();`)

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Client client = new Client();
client.setIdClient(clientId);
String queryString ="from it.besmart.models.Client where clientId = :c)";
List<?> list = session.createQuery(queryString).setProperties(client).list();
```

but I got, now,

```
org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.getRegionFactory(Settings.java:300)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1322)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:677)
at it.besmart.parkserver.SocketClientHandler.run(SocketClientHandler.java:78)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I cannot understand why, I closed the first session, but then opened a new one..

Is it correct to close the session on each query

**EDIT**
I'm trying to solve this problem, but with no result.

Now I have the first select query, which goes well. It's at the startup of the application.

```
try {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    String query = "SELECT count(*) as posti_disponibili from occupazione t inner join ";
    query += "(select id_posto_park, max(date_time) as MaxDate from occupazione group by id_posto_park) tm on ";
    query += "t.id_posto_park = tm.id_posto_park and t.date_time = tm.Maxdate and t.isOccupied = 0";

    BigInteger bi = (BigInteger) session.createSQLQuery(query).uniqueResult();
    result = bi.intValue();
}
```

I do not commit or flush it.
Then, going up with the application, I have the second query, so I getCurrentSession and try to do the select

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Client client = new Client();
client.setIdClient(clientId);
String queryString ="from it.besmart.models.Client c where c.clientId = :c";
logger.debug(queryString);
// logger.debug(session);

Query theQuery = session.createQuery(queryString).setProperties(client);
List<?> list = theQuery.list();
```

The application stops, nothing comes out, I don't know what's going on also because I cannot setup hibernate to log with pi4j...
Is there something wrong in how I use hibernate sessions?

Comment: In the first case, you call `getCurrentSession()` and in the second case you call `openSession()`. Is this what you intended?

Comment: I call getCurrentSession the first time and the query goes. Then I close the session (is it correct?) and to make the new queries I have to call openSession? Right? And why I got the exception?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, you'll obtain a "current session" which is bound to the lifecycle of the transaction and will be automatically flushed and closed when the transaction ends (commit or rollback).

If you decide to use `sessionFactory.openSession()`, you'll have to manage the session yourself and to flush and close it "manually".

For more info go to [Hibernate transactions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html).

Comment: Thank you @Abdelhak I read the documentation, but I cannot understand a thing. You said that the transaction is closed after a flush or a commit. I have just SELECT queries, so no commit is needed. Does it means I have to use always the same session, even for the following queries?