# Getting error ---org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea, gradle

I was trying a Spring Hibernate Program in intellij ide using Gradle following are my files

Spring Core Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.creativecapsule" />

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.creativecapsule.Entity.Employee" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
                          transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

Build.Gradle

```
group 'IM'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

// JDK 7
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final'
    compile 'commons-pool:commons-pool:20030825.183949'
    compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:20030825.184428'
    compile 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1'
}

// Embeded Jetty for testing
jettyRun{
    contextPath = ""
    httpPort = 8081
}

jettyRunWar{
    contextPath = ""
    httpPort = 8081
}
```

Controller

```
package com.creativecapsule.Controller;

import com.creativecapsule.Entity.Employee;
import com.creativecapsule.Service.EmployeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Created by sandip on 02/22/2017.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String saveEmployee(){
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setId(1);
        emp.setName("Ram");
        System.out.println("Check value in controller-------->" + emp.getName());
        return employeeService.saveEmployee(emp);

    }
}
```

Dao

```
package com.creativecapsule.Dao;

import com.creativecapsule.Entity.Employee;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by sandip on 02/22/2017.
 */
@Repository
@Transactional
public class EmployeeDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory session;


    public Collection<Employee> getAllEmployees()
    {
        return this.employees.values();
    }

    @Transactional
    public String saveEmployee(Employee emp){
        try {
            System.out.println("Check value in Dao-------->" + emp.getName());
            session.getCurrentSession().save(emp);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }
        return  "success";
    }
```

here is my error log

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at com.creativecapsule.Dao.EmployeeDao.saveEmployee(EmployeeDao.java:45)
    at com.creativecapsule.Service.EmployeeService.saveEmployee(EmployeeService.java:24)
    at com.creativecapsule.Controller.EmployeeController.saveEmployee(EmployeeController.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I tried @Transactional and other solutions but still it is throwing this error.

now i tried it with session.openSession().save(emp); it throws errororg.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.creativecapsule.Entity.Employee

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Hibernate - Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203446/spring-hibernate-could-not-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for-current)

Comment: For starters stop mixing jars of different spring version `4.3.6`, `4.3.4`, `4.3.3, `4.2.5`, `4.1.6`.

Comment: @RubioRic I tried that solution but still i am getting same error

Comment: now i tried it with session.openSession().save(emp); it throws errororg.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.creativecapsule.Entity.Employee

Comment: In the `packagesToScan` attribute give the package name, not the entity class. Remove '.Employee' at the end.

Comment: You need at least `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your configuration (never use openSession in a spring transactional driven app!).