# Spring @Transactional not rolling back after failure

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have a Spring `@Service` bean in which some data saving in a **MySQL** occurs. It's saving `LocalDateTime` objects, for booking rooms in future dates.

The problem is: when booking multiple rooms at once and one of them is not available (i.e. already booked), Spring should rollback all the rooms that were booked already, but isn't doing it. Everything but the error one is commited to the database.

Code inside my `@Service`, the one that should rollback after an exception is thrown.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { RecurrentMeetingBookingException.class})
public void bookRecurringMeeting(RecurrentMeeting meeting) throws RecurrentMeetingBookingException {
    LocalDateTime start = meeting.getMeetingEntity().getStartDate();
    LocalDateTime end = meeting.getMeetingEntity().getEndDate();

    while (start.isBefore(meeting.getRecurrenceEndTime())) {
        MeetingEntity recurrent = copyOfRecurrent(meeting, start, end);

        try {
            bookRoomForDate(recurrent);
        } catch (MeetingException e) {
            throw new RecurrentMeetingBookingException(e.getMessage());
        }

        start = start.plus(1, meeting.getRecurrenceType().getUnitOfTime());
        end = end.plus(1, meeting.getRecurrenceType().getUnitOfTime());
    }
}
```

I tried throwing a `RuntimeException` too, but it also didn't work.

When returning a `ResponseEntity` from my `Controller`, the exception is indeed thrown, as I return `Room is not available` as an exception, returning it's message.

---

What is the problem with my `@Transactional`? Shouldn't Spring/Hibernate rollback everything when an exception is thrown? What can I do to solve this issue, and correctly rollback the `@Transactional`?

Comment: Assuming that the `bookRecurringMeeting` method is declared in the `@Service` class named `BookService`, The `@Controller` is using how a dependency the `BookService` class?. If your `@RequestMapping` is **not** calling directly the `bookRecurringMeeting` method, then the `@Transactional` attribute is not working how is expected. Consider post your `@Controller` code. I had this behaviour too.

Comment: My problem was another one, I posted it below. Spent way too many hours finding a solution to not post it back to the community. I'll add the extra codes when I have a chance, but the `@RestController` was calling `bookRecurringMeeting` directly.

Comment: Do you have either `<tx:annotation-driven>` or `@EnableTransactionManagement` declared? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203446/spring-hibernate-could-not-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for-current/26203682#26203682

Comment: Yes, @ManuelJordan. The problem solution is described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When facing this problem, [a member from the spring forums came with a solution](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/95496-transaction-is-not-rolling-back-in-case-of-exception?p=537584#post537584), back in 2011.

---

Make sure you're using transactional tables, for example **INNODB**

You might be using a non-transactional table, for instance **MyISAM**, and `@Transactional` won't work as expected.

This isn't exactly a Spring/Hibernate problem, but your database's.