# Errors with hibernate session in spring ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I can't guess what is wrong with my configuration. I need to use hibernate method within ApplicationListener, but constantly getting this error:

```
Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

despite the usage of @Transactional under method. This is ApplicationListener implementation:

```
@Component
public class FillIdOnStartup implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>
{
    @Inject
    private MyRepository repository;


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent)
    {
        Iterable<Provider> products = repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

This is how findAll() method looks like:

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Iterable<T> findAll()
    {
        return session().createQuery("from " + entityClass.getName()).getResultList();
    }
```

What is wrong? Thank you

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203446/spring-hibernate-could-not-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for-current

Comment: Thank you. Doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to annotate onApplicationEvent with @Transactional?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem is that such things like ApplicationListener, @PostConstruct annotations are initialized BEFORE @Transactional. That is why hibernate can't get current session. The solution is to open session directly in metod and begin transaction:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
// some hibernate actions.
tx.commit();
session.close();
```