# Spring hibernate transaction annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I found that spring @Transactional should be placed in Service layer not in the DAO layer?

But when I use @Transactional(Spring) in only service layer, an exception is thrown "Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread" but when I use @Transactional(@Spring) in both DAO and Service , this issue is resolved.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203446/spring-hibernate-could-not-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for-current