# Caused by:HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not
>   valid without active transaction at
>   org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
>                         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.createCriteria(Unknown Source)

**Hibernate Configuration**

```
package com.cm;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.cm")
public class HibernateConfiguration {


    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String userName;
    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${db.jdbcurl}")
    private String jdbcurl;

    /*@Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;*/
    /*@Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String show_sql;
    @Value("${hibernate.format_sql}")
    private String format_sql;
*/
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.cm.models" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcurl);
        dataSource.setUsername(userName);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
        return hibernateTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }

}

@Service
public class TransactionService {


    private TransactionDao transactionDao;  
    private TransactionDetailsDao transactionDetailDao;

    @Autowired
    public TransactionService(TransactionDao transactionDao, TransactionDetailsDao transactionDetailDao){
        this.transactionDao = transactionDao;
        this.transactionDetailDao = transactionDetailDao;
    }
transactionDao.selectFromTransaction(bookRoomsRequest.getConfirmationNo(), bookRoomsRequest.getBookingStatus());
}

**DAO**
```

> If i am writing @Transectional then i am getting bean creation issue
>   at application start up i applied on service layer also but same
>   issue.

```
@Repository 
public class TransactionDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements TransactionDao {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean selectFromTransaction(String orderId, String type) throws SQLException {
        /*
         * String SQL_QUERY = "select * from transaction t where t.type = '" + type +
         * "' and  t.order_id='" + orderId +"';";
         */
        List<Transaction> list = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean response = false;

        try {
            Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Transaction.class);
            Criterion Type = (Restrictions.eq("type", type));
            Criterion Order_id = (Restrictions.eq("order_id", orderId));
            criteria.add(Restrictions.and(Type, Order_id));
            list = criteria.list();

            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)) {
                response = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

if i am removing `ThreadLocalSessionContext` from `hibernate configuration` then i am getting below error.

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain
>   transaction-synchronized Session for current thread   at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)

I am managing transaction properly and i tried all possibles solution([Spring Hibernate - Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203446/spring-hibernate-could-not-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for-current)) still no luck please  help to get the exact solution for this issue.

```
**On Putting @Transectional  on on selectFromTransaction method i am getting below erro Stacktrace at application statup.**
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'retryServiceImpl' defined in file [/home/saurabhsharma/Desktop/fresh_proxycm/hotels-proxy-cm/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cm-proxy-api/WEB-INF/classes/com/paytm/cm/services/impl/RetryServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: No qualifying bean of type [com.paytm.cm.dao.impl.TransactionDaoImpl] found for dependency [com.paytm.cm.dao.impl.TransactionDaoImpl]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.paytm.cm.dao.impl.TransactionDaoImpl] found for dependency [com.paytm.cm.dao.impl.TransactionDaoImpl]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1213) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1053) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:834) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.paytm.cm.dao.impl.TransactionDaoImpl] found for dependency [com.paytm.cm.dao.impl.TransactionDaoImpl]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1403) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:834) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Nov 16, 2018 11:40:53 AM org.apache.c
```

Comment: Judging from the exception you aren't managing transactions properly, else you wouldn't get the exceptions you are having. Post some code and configuration with your question, currently there is too little information.

Comment: annotate selectFromTransaction method with @Transactional

Comment: You would need to begin transaction or annotate the class with `@Transactional`. Post the stacktrace for **If i am writing @Transectional then i am getting bean creation issue at application start up i applied on service layer also but same issue**